# Ruby OpenSSL cipher initialization

Tags: ruby, openssl

I open `irb` and run the following:

```
require 'openssl/cipher'
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-128-CBC')
```

But I get the error message:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
from (irb):4:in `initialize'
from (irb):4:in `new'
from (irb):4
from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

My Ruby version:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

I am following [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html), but can't see why this isn't working.

Any ideas?

Comment: After a few test, it seems `require 'openssl'` is OK to create the cipher while `require 'openssl/cipher'` not.

Comment: Thanks @halfelf. Solved. If you put it as a proper answer I'll choose it (not sure what the etiquette is here).